# Access class from GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First and ran into a slight problem.

I have two tables as such:

```
User
+--------+-----------+
|   id   |   name    |
+--------+-----------+
| def789 | Bob Smith |
+--------+-----------+

Actions
+--------+--------------+-------------+
|   id   | grantedTo_id |   details   |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| abc123 | def789       | some detail |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
```

Pretend the 3 Id fields are GUIDs for this purpose.

My classes look something like:

```
User
{
public Guid id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
}

Actions
{
public Guid id {get; set;}
public User grantedTo {get; set;}
public string details {get; set;}
}
```

My issue is that since the class defines `grantedTo` as type User, nothing is returned in it from the database (since it is of type Guid).

So for instance if I do something simple like:

```
var action = db.Action.ToList()
foreach (var a in db.Action)
{
var user = a.GrantedTo
}
```

Then user contains null.

How do I go about getting the User referenced by the Id?

These were done code first, I've made no modifications to them. Is there a descriptor or something I should be using? I thought I could do something like:

```
var action = db.Action.ToList()
foreach (var a in action)
{
var user = db.Users.Find(...???)
}
```

But I haven't the foggiest what to put in there since the GUID isn't coming back either.

Comment: Your `Action` class should have `public virtual User grantedTo {get; set;}` and `public Guid UserId { get; set; }` to create a navigation property - refer [Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke OP already have `public User grantedTo {get; set;}`, which is enough. Neither `virtual` nor explicit FK property is *required*.

Comment: Since your `grantedTo` property is not `virtual`, it cannot be lazy loaded and you are expected to load it using eager or explicit loading. For instance,. `var action = db.Action.Include(a => a.grantedTo).ToList();` will populate the `grantedTo` property of the actions in the list.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, make that an answer and I'll accept it. It worked flawlessly and is such a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) documentation topic, EF supports three ways to load related data - eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading.

Since the `grantedTo` property is not marked as `virtual`, it's not eligible for lazy loading, which is the only way of the three in which EF loads related data automatically. While in the other two EF does that only by your explicit request, which from the other side gives you better control.

For instance, using `Include` method (eager loading)

```
var action = db.Action.Include(a => a.grantedTo).ToList();
```

will populate the `grantedTo` property of the actions in the list.

Another benefit of doing it this way is that it's compatible with EF Core which (currently) does not support lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Code First then you need to change your Action definition to:

```
public class Action
{
   [Key]
   public Guid ActionId { get; set; }
   // ...
   public Guid GrantedToId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("GrantedToId")]
   public virtual User GrantedTo { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

If you are using EF6 you can use EntityTypeConfiguration to set up the relationships without needing FK properties defined:

```
public class ActionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Action>
{
  public ActionConfiguration()
  {
    ToTable("Actions");
    HasKey(x => x.ActionId);

    HasRequired(x => x.GrantedTo)
      .WithMany()
      .Map(x => x.MapKey("GrantedToId"))
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
  }
}
```

My preference with EF is to use entity type configurations as I prefer schema-first development and it gives me more control about how the mapping will be set up. I do not like having both navigation properties and FK properties since you have public setters on both. This leaves all kinds of ugly scenarios where you might have a FK, but no reference loaded... Or when changing a reference what happens if the FK field doesn't match, or you set the FK without updating the reference.